# how to merge lists from a loop output Python

Tags: python, list, loops, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 lists output into one list from a for loop. Tried `append()` and `extend()` to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
c_files = ['file1', 'file2']
           
doc_count = 0
comb_cran = []

for fname in c_files:
    with open(fname,'r') as cr:
        cran = cr.read()
        
        doc_count = doc_count + 1        
        docID = os.path.basename(fname) 
        
        #TOKENIZING :
        
        # remove SGML Tags
        removedsgml_cran = BeautifulSoup(cran, "html.parser")
        clean_cran = removedsgml_cran.get_text()
                
        # remove non-alphanumeric
        non_alpha = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+')
        alpha = non_alpha.sub(' ', clean_cran)
        alpha_lower = alpha.lower()
                
        # word Tokenizing using nltk
        tokenized =  word_tokenize(alpha_lower)                 
             
        # combine the list
        #comb_cran.extend(tokenized) 
        
        cword_removed = [(w, docID, 1) for w in tokenized if not w in c_words]    

    print(cword_removed)
```

and the results:

```
[('1', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('experimental', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('investigation', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('aerodynamics', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('slipstream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('brenckman', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('ae', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('scs', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('25', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('1958', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('324', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('experimental', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('study', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('propeller', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('slipstream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('made', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('order', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('determine', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('spanwise', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('distribution', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('lift', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('increase', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('due', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('slipstream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('angles', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('attack', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('free', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('stream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('slipstream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('velocity', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('ratios', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('results', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('intended', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('evaluation', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('basis', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('theoretical', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('treatments', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('problem', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('comparative', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('span', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('loading', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('curves', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('supporting', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('evidence', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('showed', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('substantial', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('lift', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('increment', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('produced', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('slipstream', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('due', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('destalling', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('control', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('effect', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('integrated', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('remaining', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('lift', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('increment', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('subtracting', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('destalling', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('lift', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('found', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('agree', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('potential', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('theory', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('empirical', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('evaluation', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('destalling', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('effects', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('made', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('specific', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('configuration', 'cranfield0001', 1), ('experiment', 'cranfield0001', 1)]


[('2', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('simple', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('shear', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('past', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flat', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('plate', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('incompressible', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('fluid', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('small', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('viscosity', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('yili', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('department', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('aeronautical', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('engineering', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('rensselaer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('polytechnic', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('institute', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('troy', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('study', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('high', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('speed', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('viscous', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('past', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('dimensional', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('curved', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('shock', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('wave', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('emitting', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('nose', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('leading', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('edge', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('exists', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('inviscid', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('rotational', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('region', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('shock', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('wave', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('situation', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('arises', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('instance', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('study', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('hypersonic', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('viscous', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('past', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flat', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('plate', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('situation', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('prandtl', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('classical', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('problem', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('prandtl', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('original', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('problem', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('inviscid', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('free', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('stream', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('irrotational', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('hypersonic', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('problem', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('inviscid', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('free', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('stream', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('considered', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('rotational', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('effects', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('vorticity', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('recently', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('discussed', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('ferri', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('libby', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('present', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('paper', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('simple', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('shear', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('past', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flat', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('plate', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('fluid', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('small', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('viscosity', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('investigated', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('shown', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('problem', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('treated', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('boundary', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('layer', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('approximation', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('feature', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('free', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('stream', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('constant', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('vorticity', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('discussion', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('restricted', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('dimensional', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('incompressible', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('steady', 'cranfield0002', 1), ('flow', 'cranfield0002', 1)]
```

The results are correct, however they are separate lists printed from each loop.
I need them to be in a single list.

I tried putting the print outside of the loop, then it prints only the second list.

Comment: Did you try `list1 + list2` ?

Comment: You can try to use zip. If you want to achieve on list after another then use list.append(element) for element in secondListElements

Answer (score 1):

So here you are encountering the stack and a concept called scope.

In your program, the list in question is `cword_removed`. You only declare and initialize it within the loop. When your program gets to `cword_removed` the first time, it creates a variable of type `list` and populates it with the list comprehension you have defined. When the program goes around the loop the second time, it overwrites the variable with the new values! That's because the local variable `cword_removed` is solely within the scope of the loop.

To remedy this, declare the variable outside of the loop, and increment via list comprehension:

```
c_files =['file1','file2']

doc_count = 0
comb_cran = []
cword_removed = []

for fname in c_files:
    with open(fname,'r') as cr:
    .
    . # the rest of your code
    .
    cword_removed += [(w,docID,1) for w in tokenized if not w in c_words]
```

Comment: I was wondering how one would generalise the c_files = ['file1','file2'] for a known (large) number of entries. It isn't simply a numpy array, a this would be the worng data type (I think- also a python newbie here!)

Answer (score 0):

As you loop over the files, then you will get each list for a file. You can easily combine the list using amazing simple operator '+'. Your right codes are:

```
c_files =['file1','file2']

doc_count = 0
comb_cran = []    
total_list=[] #Your final wanted list

for fname in c_files:
    with open(fname,'r') as cr:
        ...your codes

        #Combine the list by simple '+' operator
        total_list = total_list+[(w,docID,1) for w in tokenized if not w in c_words]    

    print(cword_removed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just overwriting your list each time and then printing the new one. You can add lists. Define your list before the loop and just add the new list on to what is already there using `full_list += new_list`. and put the final print statement outside the for loop.

```
c_files =['file1','file2']

doc_count = 0
comb_cran = []
cword_removed = []


for fname in c_files:
    with open(fname,'r') as cr:
        cran = cr.read()

        doc_count = doc_count + 1        
        docID = os.path.basename(fname) 

        #TOKENIZING :

        # remove SGML Tags
        removedsgml_cran = BeautifulSoup(cran,"html.parser")
        clean_cran = removedsgml_cran.get_text()

        # remove non-alphanumeric
        non_alpha = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+')
        alpha = non_alpha.sub(' ',clean_cran)
        alpha_lower = alpha.lower()

        # word Tokenizing using nltk
        tokenized =  word_tokenize(alpha_lower)                 

        # combine the list
        #comb_cran.extend(tokenized) 

        cword_removed += [(w,docID,1) for w in tokenized if not w in c_words]    

print(cword_removed)
```